# How to import data from multiple text file to SQL server using SSIS?

Tags: ssis, flat-file

I have multiple text file in my source folder which I have to import to SQL Server using SSIS and after import all file has to moved to Archive folder. Can any one suggest me the easiest method?

Comment: This is one of the core functionalists of SSIS.  What research did you do?  What have you tried?

Comment: Step 1) Import data, Step 2) Move the files. What's the problem here?

Comment: Research the Foreach Loop Container and the File System Task.

Answer (score 1):

The first link below provides the basics of using SSIS to archive imported files.  The second link provides similar information with additional detail of renaming the archived files with a date/timestamp tag.

[Loop through files loading them and archiving them one-by-one](http://help.pragmaticworks.com/DTSxchange/scr/FAQ%20-%20How%20to%20loop%20through%20files%20in%20a%20specified%20folder,%20load%20one%20by%20one%20and%20move%20to%20archive%20folder%20using%20SSIS.htm)

[Archive files and add timestamp](https://businessanalyticsrajkumar.wordpress.com/2015/03/04/ssis-archive-files-and-add-timestamp-to-each-file-name-how-to-use-file-system-task/)

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you very much. These links provided by you has helped me to solve my problem.